# MSSQL Support for Craft?

Tags: database

Is there a MSSQL support for Craft CMS?
Or any plugin that can help to connect to a MSSQL database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're running Craft CMS 3, the [Connect plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-connect) will let you connect to MSSQL databases (local or remote)

You'll just need to do:

```
composer require yiisoft/yii2-mssql
```

...on your Craft CMS project. To be clear, this doesn't add support for MSSQL to Craft itself, it just lets you query MSSQL databases in your Twig templates.

Answer (score 2):

Craft 3 supports [MySQL 5.5+ and PostgreSQL 9.5+](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/requirements.html#server-requirements).

Craft 2 only supports [MySQL 5.1+](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/requirements.html).

Yii (the framework Craft runs on) uses [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for its database abstraction layer, which supports [many databases](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php), so technically it wouldn't be much work but it's more of a matter of the demand for it and "are we ready to support other databases".

Logically MSSQL would probably be next on the list, but there's not timeline/ETA for it.